# Internet Explorer error "connection timed out" when server does not respond

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, server

Does you have an idea about how to increase Internet Explorer 10 ReceiveTimeout (Server response time) programmatically (java , jquery , ajax)  apart from below settings.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings

Thanks